# Using Web3 v1.0.0 in a web application: issue with XHR2

Tags: web3js

I am building a simple Vue-based web application which uses Web3 v1.0.0 (the latest version available). Currently, I'm struggling to make something as simple as the following run:

```
import Web3 from 'web3'

const api = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('...', 2000))

const batch = new api.eth.BatchRequest()
batch.add(api.eth.getBalance.request('...', 'latest', (err, balance) => console.log({ err, balance })))

batch.execute()
```

This snippet runs fine in the NodeJS environemnt, but throws an error in browser:

`xml-http-request.js?37da:91 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined`

A brief investigation gave me the following:

1. Web3 HTTP provider runs requests using `XMLHttpRequest` from the `xhr2-cookies` library
2. The `XMLHttpRequest` constructor has the following line in its constructor:

`_this._userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (" + os.type() + " " + os.arch() + ") node.js/" + process.versions.node + " v8/" + process.versions.v8;`

Apparently, referencing `process` in the browser environment maks little sense and eventually causes the application to crash.

I've also checked the `dist/web3.js` in the `web3` repo: it seems to reference `xhr2-cookies` the very same way.

As a result, I have no idea how is this supposed to work in browser. Any ideas?

Comment: i have the same problem. could you solve it ?

Comment: Nope. I've decided to downgrade to 0.20.x

Comment: Same problem here